# How can I ensure that ActiveRecord is saving changes to the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, resque

I have a complex system that involves many [Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) workers, jobs, and a monitoring process. The jobs have parent-child dependencies and these run through a series of states (using [state-machine](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine)), which is the reason for the monitoring process. We depend on the database state to ensure that cross-process tracking is in sync.

Here's a rough idea:

```ruby
class ParentMonitor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many children, class: ChildMonitor

  state_machine :state, initial: :work_needed do
    event :succeed do
      transition :work_needed => :work_succeeded
    end

    event :fail do
      transition :work_needed => :work_failed
    end
  end

  def child_transition
    return if children.any? { |child| child.work_needed? }

    if children.any? { |child| child.work_succeeded? }
      succeed
    else
      fail
    end
  end
end

class ChildMonitor < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to: owner, class: ParentMonitor

  state_machine :state, initial: :work_needed do
    event :succeed do
      transition :work_needed => :work_succeeded
    end
    after_transition :to => :work_succeeded, :do => :notify_owner

    event :fail do
      transition :work_needed => :work_failed
    end
    after_transition :to => :work_failed, :do => :notify_owner
  end

  def notify_owner
    owner.child_transition
  end    
end
```

What's happening is that for the first few such jobs (say a dozen or two out of several hundred), the ParentMonitors are being left in the `work_needed` state even though all children are either in `work_succeeded` or `work_failed`. Through tracing and testing I've determined that each the time `ParentMonitor#child_transition` is called, the list of children in "work needed" state has successively been reduced until at some point it makes a database load and replaces all the children with values of "work needed". Even though some had previously been completed.

In addition I don't see any `UPDATE` logs in the log file for these first few children until it suddenly starts logging the updates. That logging is simultaneous with when it seems to reset the states of all its children.

It makes me think that the changes are all happening in memory due to some cached state, but I've added `reload`, `save` and `find` calls throughout and they don't seem to effect change. I've also tried wrapping these calls in `uncache` but that doesn't help.

Comment: wrap the persistence in an `ActiveRecord.transaction`, this would ensure that any failure would lead to a rollback of all the transactions, and you would always be in a predictable state

Comment: I think you might want to aqcuire mutexes and do some of this stuff in a more classic multithreaded scenario to check that two different jobs aren't interfering with one another, it's simple but it works well.

Comment: @bjhaid I understood that ActiveRecord already [added transactions](http://markdaggett.com/blog/2011/12/01/transactions-in-rails/) around things like `#save`. I'll try wrapping that in another transaction on the off chance that committing it forces a database write.

Comment: @MikeH-R Thanks for the suggestion, I'll dig into mutex patterns more,  but doesn't postgresql take care of handling interference from multiple processes by locking records? Can you elaborate on how I would apply a mutex to this?

Comment: @jwadsack quoting from the link you posted `As a rule, transactions are only needed when changes to multiple records must succeed as a single unit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out this was caused by the fact that the writes were held in a long-running transaction because the state-machine gem holds open a transaction between the state change and the end of any `after` hooks. We had written hooks that ran for hours on the main monitoring loop.

We resolved this by performing the actions between state changes rather than in callbacks.

Incidentally, the erroneous behavior is exactly as described in the latest [Red Book](http://www.redbook.io/ch6-isolation.html) as a side-effect of "weak isolation" concurrency implemented in most RDMBS's:

> example anomalies include reading intermediate data that another transaction produced, reading aborted data, reading two or more different values for the same item during execution of the same transaction, and “losing” some effects of transactions due to concurrent writes to the same item